# Next JS 13 Auto Refreshing Even Without Code Change And Losing The Styles

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My NextJS application sometimes is auto refreshing even without changing anything in code and when it is refreshing it takes some time to load the styles. I use SCSS and Tailwind for styling.

What's causing the auto refresh without code change? Can I disable the auto refresh and is it okay to disable it?

How can I prevent losing the styles when it is auto refreshing?

[image]

[image]